# SWT Filedialog Open into home folder

Tags: java, linux, swt, filedialog

I want to open a FileDialog window into the user home folder (i.e. /home/user or /Users/unsername)

I read the user home folder, using System.getProperty:

```
  String homefolder = System.getProperty(user.home);
```

And the variable containts the correct home folder. But when i set the filterpath in FileDialog, it opens (in linux) only the /home level not entering into the user home dir.

This is the source code:

```
  FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell); 
  dialog.setText("Choose a certificate");
  String platform = SWT.getPlatform();
  String homefolder = System.getProperty("user.home");
  dialog.setFilterPath(homefolder);
```

Any idea?
Here a screenshot: 
[image: Swt FileDialog Problem]

Comment: Your code does open the home folder on my system. Did you verify that `homefolder` is the correct path?

Comment: yeah. The homfolder content is correct. But when i open the FileDialog it is on /home with the user folder selected.

Comment: Which window manager are you using?

Comment: I use Kde as window manager. But the libraries used by swt doesn't seem to use any kde component.

Comment: There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=287149), which states "fixed". Which version of SWT are you using?

Comment: <version>3.3.0-v3346</version>

Comment: Well, there is your problem. It was fixed in 3.4. So, go ahead and just use a newer version. If this worked for you, I will create an answer that you can accept.

Comment: Yeah it worked :) (the problem was that i was using maven, and the official repository support only versions 3.2 and 3.3, i added another repository http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096299/maven-project-swt-3-5-dependency-any-official-public-repo if you want you can add that in your answer). Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works perfectly with SWT 3.6.1. There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=287149) stating that this was a problem in SWT versions <= 3.3 and was fixed in 3.4.

So, the solution would be to install a never version (ideally the current version).

Since you mentioned that you use a Maven repository, there is one for SWT 3.8 here:

[maven project: SWT 3.5 dependency: any official public repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096299/maven-project-swt-3-5-dependency-any-official-public-repo)