# Is it possible to use SWT on Android-Studio or IntelliJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea, swt

I've used Android-Studio for a long time, and I got used to it over Eclipse.

I wish to create an SWT app for PCs (windows, Linux, macOs) , and use a nice UI mechanism like Window-Builder that used to exist for Eclipse.

Is it a possible thing to do on Android-Studio or IntelliJ ?

If so, how?

Comment: What I don't get ... why do you want to use android-studio to create a non-android app? And keep in mind: Jetbrains claims that IntelliJ is such great technology because they focus on delivering the best-in-class Java editor to you. You know, when you want the powerful platform with all the many plugins ... maybe you should check on eclipse again. Finally; isn't that one of these "tooling/library" questions that only newbies ask for? ;-)

Comment: I ask this because Android-Studio is based on IntelliJ anyway, and having 2 IDEs that are about the same is not needed. About Eclipse, it's just the editing of SWT apps that I want to have. Last sentence isn't something I can answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no visual UI editor like WindowBuilder to create SWT UIs in IntelliJ.

But you certainly can create SWT applications with IntelliJ or any other non-Eclipse IDE for that matter. In my opinion, UI designer are overrated and UIs can be equally well implemented *by hand*. Thus if you are willing implement the UI in code you simply need to get a copy of the SWT library and you are set.

If you follow the redirects from this question it will guide you to maven artifacts of SWT:
[maven project: SWT 3.5 dependency: any official public repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096299/maven-project-swt-3-5-dependency-any-official-public-repo?lq=1)

Note that SWT comes with a native part that might make extra settings necessary to launch your application.

Comment: I mostly use UI designers for preview of what I did, and to learn how to handle relatively new/rare stuff. It was a very long time ago that I used SWT, so a UI designer can help a lot. I use the UI designer on Android-Studio mainly to show how it looks, because there, there is a huge time wasted on build&run (time from when you press Run, till it actually runs on the device). About IntelliJ, that's too bad. Thank you.

Comment: I see, makes sense of course. With SWT the time to start an application is tremendously shorter than on Andoid. There is a collections of self-contained snippets that demonstrate commonly used features of a widget https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/ to start with. That's of course not as fast as the feedback cycle of a visual designer. Seems your choice is to go back to Eclipse for the visual designer or live with the lag in IntelliJ or use a different UI toolkit altogether. Or use Eclipse only to try things out.

Comment: indeed. Also, now that I started SWT again, I have to say that Android UI handling is much easier to handle, in terms of readability , which UI-components are available, and the connection between them.