# Import SWT as a Gradle dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, swt

I am looking at how to import the SWT UI library into my Java project.
I found the pom file for SWT on maven at: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/swt/3.3.0-v3346/swt-3.3.0-v3346.pom

From the file I added the following line to my `build.gradle` file

```
compile "org.eclipse:swt:3.3.0"
```

however when I added it to my `build.gradle` I received the following error:

```
Project 'L-CAD Main' is missing required library: '/home/ashley/unresolved dependency - org.eclipse swt 3.3.0'
```

If I understand this right this means it can't find the dependency, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My IDE is Eclipse.

Comment: The full version of the SWT maven artifact is `3.3.0-v3346`. Therefore your Grade dependency should reference `org.eclipse:swt:3.3.0-v3346` as well, or am I wrong with this?

Comment: BTW for more recent versions of SWT maven artifacts see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096299/maven-project-swt-3-5-dependency-any-official-public-repo

Comment: yea that fixed it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the whole package name in the dependency line, including the version number.

Therefore add: `compile "org.eclipse:swt:3.3.0-v3346"` to the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: This does not work anymore. The class files are removed from the JAR. The best way for now, I think, is to download the JAR apart and add it as local dependency(without using Gradle).

Answer (score 0):

When using JCenter with Gradle for compiling Eclipse SWT.

The Repository that Gradle pulls from for SWT is [JCenter SWT](https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/swt/).

Edit your `gradle.build` accordingly. You need to add the compile line to the `dependencies` [closure](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) of your `Grable.build`. For example, if you want to build for 64 bit Linux use:

```
compile 'org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64:4.3'
```

According to [Eclipse Foundation](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/),

> SWT is an open-source widget toolkit for Java designed to provide efficient, portable access to the user-interface facilities of the operating systems on which it is implemented.

This means that unlike other Java GUI tool kits like [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)), SWT does not provide its own widgets, but allows you to write one Java UI that can use with a platform-specific implementation of SWT for the desired OS, like windows or mac.

For your desired Operating System, you will want to select the corresponding library version from [JCenter SWT](https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/swt/), where the compile line from `gradle.build` should reflect:

```
compile 'org.eclipse.swt:<target platform>:4.3'
```

Where `<target platform>` for example is `org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64/` or `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64/`.