# Import SWT the Gradle way in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, swt

What is the correct way for importing SWT the Gradle way in a Eclipse Java project?

The following solution on Stackoverflow does not work (it imports a tiny SWT library containing no classes, I can't make use of any SWT functionality):

[Import SWT as a Gradle dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117049/import-swt-as-a-gradle-dependency)

My application needs to use SWT UI classes and widgets (eg. Display, Shell, Composites and so on) and must absolutely be cross-platform.

Note that my application also uses LWJGL, which I can import successfully using the page below which does provide the full Gradle code to use (click build under Release then select Gradle):

[LWJGL build.gradle import code](https://www.lwjgl.org/download)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of your Gradle build file?

Comment: My build.gradle file is the following (that's what you get when you create a new plain Gradle project in Eclipse): http://pastebin.com/w6fESNip. What am I supposed to declare to properly import SWT and make everything cross platform?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Eclipse 4.6.2, SWT (and all of Eclipse) is published to maven central. If you're using Gradle, the goomph plugin has a mavencentral plugin that makes it pretty easy:

```
apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.gradle.eclipse.mavencentral'
eclipseMavenCentral {
  release '4.7.0', {
    compile 'org.eclipse.swt'
    useNativesForRunningPlatform()
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not work; `eclipseMavenCentral` is not recognised. Better paste full gradle script.

Comment: Maybe these links will help: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.diffplug.gradle.eclipse.mavencentral and https://diffplug.github.io/goomph/javadoc/3.17.3/com/diffplug/gradle/eclipse/MavenCentralPlugin.html

Comment: OK that indeed works. Gradle just gave me SWT 3.106. OK this is the way, just make it a complete answer and notify the OP to accept it. What I did was to add  `id "com.diffplug.gradle.eclipse.mavencentral" version "3.17.3"` under `plugin {}` part. PS: I hope Eclipse team could make it more clear so we don't have to search here instead of in the documentation.....

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer of @Ned Twigg, the full `build.gradle` file should be like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "com.diffplug.gradle.eclipse.mavencentral" version "3.17.3"
}
...
apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.gradle.eclipse.mavencentral'
eclipseMavenCentral {
    release '4.7.0', {
        compile 'org.eclipse.swt' // SWT for Windows in Gradle
        useNativesForRunningPlatform()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure the differences between an eclipse plugin and an SWT application but you might be able to use the [buildship build](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/blob/master/build.gradle) as a reference. The [buildSrc](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/tree/master/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/eclipsebuild) utilities may be of use.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, there is an awful quantity of things in this build.gradle file. I am not using a Plug-in project, just a plain Java Gradle project. Would you mind helping me isolate the lines that are relevant to SWT and merge these lines into the above-provided code (see pastebin link)?

Comment: "Would you mind helping me isolate the lines that are relevant to SWT and merge these lines into the above-provided code" no thanks

Answer (score 0):

** Disclaimer ** I've never used SWT before

I'd put the SWT jars in a maven-like directory structure (note I've chosen random group/artifact/version here... please adjust appropriately)

```
myRepo/com/eclipse/swt/swt-core/4.1/swt-core-4.1-windows.jar
myRepo/com/eclipse/swt/swt-core/4.1/swt-core-4.1-linux.jar
myRepo/com/eclipse/swt/swt-utils/4.1/swt-utils-4.1-windows.jar
myRepo/com/eclipse/swt/swt-utils/4.1/swt-utils-4.1-linux.jar
```

You could do something like this in `build.gradle`

```
org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.OperatingSystem os = org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current()
def osDeps = []
if (os.windows) {
    osDeps = ['com.eclipse.swt:swt-core:4.1:windows', 'com.eclipse.swt:swt-utils:4.1:windows']
} else if (os.linux) {
    osDeps = ['com.eclipse.swt:swt-core:4.1:linux', 'com.eclipse.swt:swt-utils:4.1:linux']
} else ... {
}

apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    maven {
        url file('myRepo')
    }
}
dependencies {
   compile 'com.foo:common-stuff:1.0'
   compile osDeps 
}
```

Or if the SWT jars are available in a maven repository you should use that instead of a local folder.

Comment: That doesn't work. One solution that kind of works is the one listed in this file : https://github.com/breskeby/gradle-eclipse-plugin/blob/master/plugins/org.gradle.eclipse/org.gradle.eclipse.gradle
I am using core.commands too, and "compile 'org.eclipse:core.commands:3.+'" doesn't work, although "core:commands" works. I guess this is because we use different repositories. What a mess.